# Trying to import a string using python in Zapier

Tags: python, regex, zapier

I'm using the Zapier code action with python to try and extract the name from this following message:

```
_id: 57455fc20913b2f400c2671d
actions: []
authorId: 0d0e129c5913b613a49531b9
name: Tiny Meerkat
received: 1464164290.1
role: appUser
source: {u'type': u'web'}
text: Hello
```

Using this code:

```
import re
name = re.search('(?<=name:)(.*?)(?=received)', input['messages'])
return {
    'name': name if name else 'empty'
}
```

The value returned is always empty. Does anyone have any ideas why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this

```
name = re.search('(?s)(?<=name:)(.*?)(?=received)', x).group(1).strip("\n\r ")
                  <-->                                 <------>
        Allows . to match new line       Returns content of first captured group
```

You have to use `(?s)` because the string is separated in different lines. Using `(?s)`, `.` matches the new line also.